# Twitter Bootstrap: navbar not resized on orientation change (only with Android's stock browser)

Tags: android, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

My Twitter Bootstrap mobile page has a fixed-top navbar

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
```

I would expect that an orientation change event would trigger a "resize" of the navbar, on a mobile device (a resize event on a desktop does correctly trigger a resize of the navbar). On the right side of the navbar I have a collapsible navbar-toggle, which opens/closes the main menu: when changing orientation from landscape to portrait, the menu button is no more visible, which is a disaster...

The issue can be verified also with the official navbar-fixed-top example (at http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/).

I'm using the stock (default) browser on a Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.1.2.

The issue does not occur on iPhone (3) browser.

**UPDATE:**
The issue persists with Android 4.3.

Comment: I can only suppose the issue occurs only on Android, since so far I've tested only *one* Android device and *one* iPhone device...

Comment: With Google Chrome installed on the same Android device the issue does *not* occur.

Comment: Works on stock browser on Android 4.2.2 on a Samsung S4.

Comment: Works on stock browser on Android 4.1.2 on a LG LG-P760 device. It looks like a Galaxy-S3 stock browser issue...

Comment: Submitted an issue on Android issue tracker page...

Comment: Am experiencing similar issues on an Android 4.0.4 device. When rotating, the navbar will resize correctly (eventually, takes a while depending on page complexity) - but there's a repaint issue. There's a chunk missing out of the navbar background on the right. I've uploaded an screen capture of the issue here: http://imgur.com/VsLVu6x

Comment: FWIW, in the mean time - I will be disabling the fixed aspect of the navbar and make it position relative instead. This appears to be rendering better.

Comment: @jfroom: Yes. Currently I'm using navbar-static-top (I will hpefully not need any content higher than one page...), which draws correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean. but write up your own CSS with all your Size stuff and add !important after it and before the ;
Something like this:

```
.navbar-whatever {
whateverSizeCode = 0 !important;
whateverSizeCode2 = 0 !important;
}
```

Put Mobile tags for Twitter Bootstrap. Here is a link for you: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-mobile

Mobile Code for you. Add this in your  tag

```
<!-- Scroll Enabled --> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- Scroll Disabled -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Note: Use any one of the two lines.

Also make sure that in your HTML you do this:

```
<style rel="stylesheet" link="bootstrap.css">
<style rel="stylesheet" link="yourCSS.css">
```

What this will do is Put your styles and sizes in a way that Bootstrap is read by the code first then your CSS so that it does not override your CSS.
Hope so I Helped. Ask me again and be more specific.

Comment: How is it you are not sure what I mean? Just load the cited official navbar-fixed-top example (at http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/) on - for example - a Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.0.4 (I have not full device/os statistics, sorry...). Then turn your device by 90° and see what happens to navbar... I do not want some css trick to bypass the bug, I just want to publish this issue to be known and fixable...

Comment: @MarcoS bro if u wanna publish this issue then tell Twitter. Stack Over Flow for solutions. As you wish. I just tried giving a solution.